# LLVM 3.6: Wrong version of Visual Studio being called while installing a python package

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, llvm-clang

I am trying to install a python package, Cmonster which is a c++ wrapper for python on my system.

It uses LLVM and I have version 3.6 installed. And I have both MSVC 2010 and MSVC 2012 on my system.
LLVM 3.6 needs MSVC 2012 to work.

I am getting the following error when i run the python install command.

[image]

MSVC 2010's cl.exe is being called here. It should call 2012. How to do that?